# How to increase size of the text in imagestring() php without using imagettftext() in PHP

Tags: php, web, gd, generate

I have searched many questions on internet that show how to increase the size of text in `imagestring()`. They suggest to use `imagettftext()` but actually this doesn't work for me. Is there any way that I can increase the text size in `imagestring()` itself. And if that is not possible help me solve the black screen error I am getting.

> Here is the PHP code:
>   `header('content-type:image/jpeg');

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg("sample.jpg");
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 225, 0, 0);

imagestring($image, 40, 100, 1000, 'sample', $color);

imagejpeg($image);

imagedestroy($image);
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is `40` there btw?

Answer (score 0):

OK! So for some reasons I wasn't able to use `imagettftext()` So I thought of using `imageftttext()`. Hopefully that's the right one :D. It works the same as you would expect `imagettftext()` to work. Cool! Hopefully this helps to the ones those who were stuck.